# Unable to connect to chriseaton adventureworks docker image

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I installed Adventureworks docker image for Microsoft SQL Server from: https://hub.docker.com/r/chriseaton/adventureworks

I am also able to start that container, as you can see here:
[image]

Now, I want to test the connection to SQL Server-AdventureWorks database using ODBC.

However, it gives failure to connect. I am using 'sa' as username and 'my_password' to connect, as given in the URL mentioned above. Any help please?

[image]

[image]

command line output:
[image]

Comment: The person who voted to close this question. Can you let me know, what is wrong with the question?